# Are the phrases "this is very interesting to me" and "this interests me a lot" interchangeable?

Tags: american-english

are the phrases

> this is very interesting to me

and

> this interests me a lot

interchangeable?

I just wanted to know because I am very curious. Are the two phrases interchangeable? I hear them a lot but I was wondering if they were interchangeable.

Comment: You would do better to drop the use of *very* in the first sentence, focusing only on the difference between *this is interesting* and *this interests me*. The addition of *very* in the first sentence adds a nuance that detracts from your question.

Comment: When asking a question:  (1) Make sure the body text contains the question, and not just the title.  (2) Use a spell checker. You should never spell a word wrong if it is in the dictionary. (3) Give an example of where you heard both expressions. (if you hear them a lot, it should be easy) (4) Tell us how you came here.  What have you done or thought about this already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"This interests me" and "this is interesting to me" do essentially mean the same, but to my ears as a native British English speaker, there is a slightly different inference.

"This interests me" is the more natural phrase of the two, and doesn't really infer anything beyond the face value. If you said that football interests you, for example, that would not really be remarkable as lots of people like football.

"This is interesting to me" does sound like you mean that something is of *particular interest* to you - and perhaps not so much to other people. It wouldn't necessarily mean that - but it could imply it. It would sound a little odd to say, for example "football is interesting to me", because it is interesting to a lot of people.

Comment: please are they the same

Comment: @RaychatuS To summarise my answer - they have the same meaning to the person saying it, but they could mean different things to the listener.

Comment: Than you the most astralbee

Comment: so they are different astralbee

Comment: @RaychatuS They have different *inferences* as I have explained, but they are not completely different and *could* be used to mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you the most astralbee

Answer (score 1):

I like what Astralbee said, and agree, but have an additional possibility.

As a native Canadian English speaker, I would say "This interests me" about a general subject (e.g., hockey, science fiction, movies) as in "Movies interest me"  or Understanding how things work interests me".

I would use "This is interesting to me" (or more commonly "Interesting!" or "This is interesting") in reference to a specific fact or event.  Say a friend was talking about an experience they had: "Do you want to hear about the time I ..." or "I know this great restaurant we could go to ..." and you would say "Yes, please continue - this is interesting (to me)"

Comment: please michael are they interchangeable thank you the most for the answer

Comment: like I (and Astralbee) said, you COULD switch the above (i.e., say "Movies are interesting" and "Yes, please continue - this interests me") and people would generally understand what you mean, but it does not sound as good/natural to me